# Sencha Touch - Can't use destroy method

Tags: extjs, touch

I can't destroy a navigationView, when I try, receive the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getScroller' of undefined "

I don't understand, when I load on Chrome browser don't receive any error message, but when put in production mode the problem appears.
I'm trying to destroy like this:

```
finalizaJanela: function()
{

    Ext.getCmp('buscacli').destroy();
    var page2 = Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Android.view.CadClientes'));
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(page2);
},
```

Someone knows how to solve?

Comment: Can you provide some more code? Especially from your buscacli component. To fix such kind of error you have to take a look at the component which has the scroller. It seems that for some reason this component is destroyed before the scroller is.

Comment: I fixed the problem, before to call destroy method, I used the reset() , later removeAll(false, false) and next the destroy method. I don't know if this is the best way to solve but it solved my problem.